# PHP scope issues in loops

Tags: php, loops, scope

I tried searching but cannot figure just why this fails.

```
    public function slim_items( $faties ) {

    $smallies = array ();
    global $faties;

    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/modules/CLBasicItem.php';
    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/helpers.php';

    foreach ($faties as $fat){
        $smallies[]=new CLBasicListItem($fat);
    }

    return $smallies;

}
```

This function being part of a class. The problem is once the foreach (and I've tried a simple for) loop starts running, $fat becomes null. It does not reference $faties once it enters the scope of the loop.

What am I doing wrong here, please? Does $faties really have to be declared global? I note you cannot even declare them global as class fields.

If anyone could help recommend an opensource IDE other than Eclipse for PHP I'd be much obliged. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but I'm finding simple tasks like stepping through code and setting up breakpoints to be quite the ordeal. All manners of exceptions I come across and the IDE/stack does little to show actual cause or misses the problem completely. Indeed, the messages PHP/Apache send out by default when there's an error are usually much more useful than what eclipse provides the odd time it does catch an exception.

EDITS: Answered better below, but I could have sworn I tried the code without declaring $faties as global (or even at all) and it didn't work. I eneded up with the more convulted

```
public function slim_items( $faties ) {

    global $uglies, $smallies;
    $uglies=$faties;
    $smallies = array ();

    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/modules/CLBasicItem.php';
    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/helpers.php';

    foreach ($uglies as $fat){
        $smallies[]=new CLBasicListItem($fat);
    }

    return $smallies;

}
```

And couldn't return to check here till now. Thanks guys, as your solutions are clearly better

Comment: `var_dump($faties);`

Comment: You redeclare `$faties`, `global $faties;` overrides param. Simply remove this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
public function slim_items( $faties ) {

    $smallies = array ();
    // global $faties; <-- this is already declared

    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/modules/CLBasicItem.php';
    require_once 'wp-content/plugins/cl-rest/helpers.php';

    foreach ($faties as $fat){
        $smallies[]=new CLBasicListItem($fat);
    }

    return $smallies;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note `public function slim_items( $faties ) {` and `global $faties;` you're redeclaring `$fatties` as
 global.